# Paste string into console line for user edit?

Tags: java, string, console

I want to print a string to the console, and then be able to backspace it and type over it and feed it back into the program. I was thinking something like this:

`System.console().readLine("hi");`

This code puts the text where I want it, but I can't edit it.
Any ideas?

Comment: That's not how the console works. You can print things and you can read things, but you cannot edit output.

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat using Scanner. Print to the console, copy/paste edit and it will read it to value.

```
System.out.println("some String");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String editable = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println(editable);
```

Comment: So this requires the user to copy "some string" and paste it and then edit?